# How do I get rid of NaNs in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, nan

I have files which have many empty cells which appear as NaNs when I use `cell2mat`, but the problem is when I need to get the average values I cannot work with this as it shows error with NaN. In excel it overlooks NaN values, so how do I do the same in MATLAB?

In addition, I am writing a file using `xlswrite`:

```
xlswrite('test.xls',M);
```

I have data in all rows except 1. How do I write:

```
M(1,:) = ('time', 'count', 'length', 'width')
```

In other words, I want `M(1,1)='time'`, `M(1,2)='count'`, and so on. I have data from `M(2,1)` to `M(10,20)`. How can I do this?

Comment: @Paul: Is the matrix `M` a cell array? I assume it has to be if it contains both strings and data values. In that case, the command `xlswrite('test.xls',M);` seems like it should work properly. What seems to be going wrong with it?

Comment: i do not  think M is cell , its a matrix of 10,20 with numbers. How do i convert in string if thats what i need.

Comment: i modified the ans to address ur newer question. hope it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use  ' isfinite ' function  to get rid of all NaN and infinities

A=A(isfinite(A))

> %create the cell array containing the column headers
> columnHeader = {'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5',' '};
>
> %write the column headers first
> xlswrite('myFile1.xls', columnHeader );
>
> % write the data directly underneath the column headers
> xlswrite('newFile.xls',M,'Sheet1','A2');

Comment: >check out:
>http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html

Answer (score 9):

[As AP correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464651/52738), you can use the function [`isfinite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html) to find and keep only finite values in your matrix. You can also use the function [`isnan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html). However, removing values from your matrix can have the unintended consequence of reshaping your matrix into a row or column vector:

```
>> mat = [1 2 3; 4 NaN 6; 7 8 9]  % A sample 3-by-3 matrix

mat =

     1     2     3
     4   NaN     6
     7     8     9

>> mat = mat(~isnan(mat))  % Removing the NaN gives you an 8-by-1 vector

mat =

     1
     4
     7
     2
     8
     3
     6
     9
```

Another alternative is to use some functions from the [Statistics Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) (if you have access to it) that are designed to [deal with matrices containing NaN values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/data-with-missing-values.html). Since you mention taking averages, you may want to check out [`nanmean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html):

```
>> mat = [1 2 3; 4 NaN 6; 7 8 9];
>> nanmean(mat)

ans =

     4     5     6     % The column means computed by ignoring NaN values
```

---

**EDIT:** To answer your additional question on the use of [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html), this sample code should illustrate one way you can write your data:

```
C = {'time','count','length','width'};  % A cell array of strings
M = rand(10,20);                        % A 10-by-20 array of random values
xlswrite('test.xls',C);           % Writes C to cells A1 through D1
xlswrite('test.xls',M,'A2:T11');  % Writes M to cells A2 through T11
```

Comment: Thanks , however i did not try this as the isfinite worked for me ,as all i wanted was to get averages.

Comment: @Paul: If the data you're averaging is just a 1-D vector, then you wouldn't have to worry about the reshaping issue I address above. The simple solution from AP is all you'd really need. ;)

Comment: @Paul: I added an example to my answer addressing your additional question.

Comment: @gnoice : looking at your solution. It still changes the size from 3X3 to  8x1 matrix..
Is there a way to get rid of rows which has NaN?
i mean if there is a NaN , like in row two , it deletes it and gives a  2X3 matrix

Comment: @AP: If you want to delete an *entire* row if there is even 1 NaN value there, the following should work: `mat = mat(~any(isnan(mat),2),:);`

Comment: @gnoice : Ialways have problem with cell and num. this command isnan does not work with cells.  ' num2cell' converts to cell , how do you get back? ' cell2mat' ??

Comment: @AP: CELL2MAT or CAT can be used to convert a cell array back to a numeric matrix. If you wanted to remove the rows of a cell array that contain at least 1 cell with a NaN value, you could instead do the following: `mat = mat(~any(cellfun(@isnan,mat),2),:);`

Answer (score 5):

Statistics Toolbox has several statistical functions to deal with NaN values. See nanmean, nanmedian, nanstd, nanmin, nanmax, etc.

Comment: By the way, min/max work the same as nanmin/nanmax. It is for mean and median where you have to use the nanX functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set NaN's to an arbitrary number like so:

```
mat(isnan(mat))=7 // my lucky number of choice.
```

Answer (score 0):

May be too late, but...

```
x = [1 2 3; 4 inf 6; 7 -inf NaN];
x(find(x == inf)) = 0; //for inf
x(find(x == -inf)) = 0; //for -inf
x(find(isnan(x))) = 0; //for NaN
```